# How to add transparent border OpenCV copymakeborder

Tags: opencv

I have 26 PNG files, each with an image of a letter of the alphabet. They've all been fully cropped to the letter shape with the result that when I insert them into an image, letters with tails all 'sit on the line'

Each letter is in black, with a transparent background. Each PNG has different dimensions, because of the differing letter shapes

I thought I'd remediate this by adding a transparent border of a different size depending on the source file, to make common datum for all the letters, so that 'a' for example would have some transparent space at the bottom.

I've coded up the calculcation for each letter, but I have two issues:

1) Even before applying the operation, I can't seem to read the file in and write it to a new unchanged file in OpenCV. The transparency in the image is replaced with black.

2) While I can add a colour border, I can't seem to add a transparent border.

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Read in, and written out:

[image: Read in, and written out]

Apparenly with a blue border, but maximum transparancy:

[image: Apparenly with a blue border, but maximum transparancy]

I have a feeling that if I can sort out the first problem, the second might fall in line. Here is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread(file)

img_with_border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[-255,0,0,255])
#img_with_border = img

cv2.imwrite(newfile, img_with_border, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100])
```

I'd appreciate some help on what is going on here with transparancy. Is OpenCV the right tool to use?

Thanks,

Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

To load a PNG image with 4 channels in OpenCV, use `im = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`. You will obtain a BGRA image.

To change the alpha value, you have to change the fourth channel of the image. This means that to create your transparent border you have to pass a value `(B, G, R, 0)` and not `[-255, 0, 0, 255]`. (What is that -255 by the way ?). B, G and R can be 0, it doesn't matter.

Also, make sure you write to a PNG image to keep the transparency. You seem to be writing your result as JPEG.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. That sounds like exactly what I need. I've implemented the IMREAD_UNCHANGED feature, but the background is still being set to black. I can see the alpha channel when I open the source file in GIMP but it's missing in the output.

Comment: Do I need to do something similar when writing the output file, to get it to include the alpha channel?

Comment: @Jeff I think it is OK like this. Make sure you're writing to a file with a `.png` extension. You can read [the documentation on imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imwrite) for more details.

Comment: It's sorted - After incorporating all the fixes you suggested, I also switched the output file back to png, and it all worked. The -255 was my attempt to include the alpha channel - I'd been trying many different combinations and possibilities.

Comment: probably not surprising given I now see via google that jpeg doesn't support transparency. Thanks for your help!